# TypeScript errors when editing old Vue 3 components but not on new components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to convert my Vue 3 single page component scripts to use TypeScript.

When I create a brand new `Test.vue` component that looks like this, I get no TypeScript errors my Visual Studio Code editor:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, inject, ref } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  //Some code here
});
</script>
```

This is as expected because my code conforms to the [Vue 3 TypeScipt docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#using-with-composition-api).

But when I convert my other existing `ExternalApi.vue` component to the same thing I am seeing errors on `defineComponent`, `inject`, and `ref`:

`Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'XXXX'. Did you mean to use 'import XXXX from "vue"' instead?`

So why does a brand new `Test.vue` component work but not the edited `ExternalApi.vue` component?

Here is the full `ExternalApi.vue` component I am trying to convert to TypeScript:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="mb-5">
      <h1>External API</h1>
      <p>
        Call Fauna.
      </p>

      <button class="btn btn-primary m-5" @click.prevent="callApi">
        Call API
      </button>
      <label for="product-name">Product Name:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        v-model="productValue"
        id="product-name"
        name="product-name"
      /><br /><br />
      <button class="btn btn-primary m-5" @click.prevent="createProduct">
        Create Product
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="result-block-container">
      <div :class="['result-block', executed ? 'show' : '']">
        <h6 class="muted">Result</h6>
        {{ JSON.stringify(apiMessage, null, 2) }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, inject, ref } from "vue";
import { query as q, Client } from "faunadb";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Api",
  setup() {
    let productValue = ref("");
    let apiMessage = ref(null);
    let executed = ref(false);
    const auth = inject("Auth");

    const callApi = async () => {
      const accessToken = await auth.getTokenSilently();
      try {
        const client = new Client({
          secret: accessToken,
          domain: "db.us.fauna.com",
          port: 443,
          scheme: "https",
        });
        const { Paginate, Documents, Collection } = q;

        const data = await client.query(
          Paginate(Documents(Collection("products")))
        );
        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(data);
        apiMessage.value = data;
        executed.value = true;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        apiMessage = `Error: the server responded with '${e.response.status}: ${e.response.statusText}'`;
      }
    };

    const createProduct = async () => {
      const accessToken = await auth.getTokenSilently();
      try {
        const client = new Client({
          secret: accessToken,
          domain: "db.us.fauna.com",
          port: 443,
          scheme: "https",
        });
        const { Create, Collection, CurrentIdentity } = q;

        const data = await client.query(
          Create(Collection("products"), {
            data: {
              name: productValue.value,
              owner: CurrentIdentity(),
            },
          })
        );
        console.log("productValue data", data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        apiMessage = `Error: the server responded with '${e.response.status}: ${e.response.statusText}'`;
      }
    };

    return {
      callApi,
      createProduct,
      apiMessage,
      executed,
      productValue,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

On top of that, when compiling via `npm run serve` the terminal throws the same errors for both `Test.vue` and `ExternalApi.vue`.

But it should not be showing errors at all because both of them [conform to the Vue docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#using-with-composition-api).

So what is going on here?

UPDATE:

This is what my `shims-vue.d.ts` file contains. I'm not actually sure what this file does, but it was in the cloned repo:

```
/* eslint-disable */
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

And this is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "replicator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 3000",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.13.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "3.0.0-3",
    "ansi-html": "^0.0.7",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "element-plus": "^1.0.2-beta.28",
    "faunadb": "^4.4.1",
    "glob-parent": "^6.0.2",
    "set-value": "^4.1.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.20",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.11",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "7.3.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-element-plus": "~0.0.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the error show up again if you restart vscode? Sometimes the editor has caching issues with typescript.

Comment: No change after restarting. The strange thing is when compiling with `npm run serve` it shows errors in the terminal for both the fresh component and the edited one. But in vscode it only shows errors for the edited component. And the strangest thing of all is that I don't think there should be any errors at all because it conforms to the docs: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#using-with-composition-api

Comment: Hmm, do you have an `sfc.d.ts` or similar SFC types file in the repo? What does it contain?

Comment: @KevinTaylor I'm not sure if it's the same thing, but I have updated the question with the `shims-vue.d.ts` file if that's helps.

Comment: Is the repo you cloned a public one you can link to?

Comment: This is my repo: https://github.com/BenJackGill/auth0-vue3-ts. And it was forked from here: https://github.com/alexeyzimarev/auth0-vue3-ts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix these import errors by upgrading TypeScript from 3.9.3 to 4.4.4: `npm install typescript@latest`

It seems that Vue 3.2.0 and above [makes use of TS features](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#320-2021-08-09) in its declaration files that require an upgraded TypeScript. `This release ships TypeScript typings that rely on Template Literal Types and requires TS >= 4.1.`

Why did question asker run into this problem in their forked repo, but not the original one? This is because the original repo required vue `^3.0.0`, but TypeScript `~3.9.3`.

Normally `yarn.lock` would ensure the same specific versions were installed, but when they switched from `yarn` to `npm`, the lockfile was regenerated, causing a version conflict when vue was upgraded but not typescript.

This problem is a good example of the importance of lockfiles!

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, but I ran `npm install typescript@latest` and I am still seeing the same import errors. Have pushed an update to the repo with those changes.

Comment: Actually I take that back, I reloaded vscode and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

This error can appear if you're trying to use the Vue 3 composition API, but you have Vue 2 installed. Currently if you run `npm install vue` you'll get version 2; you need to run `npm install vue@next` to get version 3.

If you want to use version 2, the basic TypeScript approach for [component definition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage) is instead like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  // type inference enabled
})
</script>
```

I recommend trying [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) and [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) if you want to use TypeScript with Vue 2, they're really great!

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was running Vue 3 but it was a cloned repo so I might have been on Vue 2 by mistake.  I ran `npm install vue@next` which removed the errors from inside vscode, but the errors are still showing in the terminal with the command `npm run serve`.

Comment: Do you have `@types/vue` installed? Maybe try `npm uninstall @types/vue`, in case it's interfering with the native vue types.

Comment: No I do not have `@types/vue` installed.

Comment: I have added `package.json` to the question in case that helps.